# Add a combination of words to dictionary in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

The term 'fuel gauge' doesn't translate to my native language, so I'm using it in English. Occurrence of either of the individual terms in my document would be in error, but the combination (or it's plural) would be valid.

In Microsoft Word 2013, how can I add *a combination* of words to the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your `custom.dic` file manually and adding the phase that way. Not sure if it works but it certainly lets you add things manually. Each "word" is on a separate line.

You should find the file in:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\UProof
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2013 go to File > Options. In options go to the proofing section where you will find the button "Custom Dictionaries." In the Custom Dictionaries window, select your dictionary and click the "Edit Word List..." button. [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322198) from Microsoft has more information.

Comment: I can add the words this way, though it still is still marked as invalid in the document.